# ghidra rename fails

Tags: ghidra, decompile

With ghidra 9.2.1 (2020 dec 15) in a decompiled dll, I can rename a variable with L.

- Sometimes (can't find a repro), when I rename a second local variable (it does not appear in listing/assembly), the previous rename is cancelled.
- Sometimes (idem), I can't rename one specific variable at all.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I've encountered similar rename issues multiple times since Ghidra was initially released. I haven't been able to track down a root cause or solution, unfortunately. Point being, I don't think you're missing anything; Ghidra just has rename issues sometimes. Maybe related: https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/193

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a *real* answer but a few hints that might help solving the issue at hand:

As already stated in the comments, Ghidra still has a few issues, one example being: https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/193. So maybe, you should open up another issue on Github using the most recent Ghidra version and a minimum example to reproduce the issue. In my experience, the developers are very helpful and react to every opened issue.

After renaming a variable, Ghidra will re-run the analysis of the currently displayed function. In some phase of this analysis it then seems to decide to get rid of the variable you *just* renamed. And for some reason it *then* sometimes decides to introduce a new variable doing the exact same thing your renamed (and now removed) variable did before with a new name. This effectively looks as if the rename was canceled.

In my experience it sometimes help to **Commit Local Names** and/or **Commit Params/Return** (select it from the context menu of the Decompiler view). I realize, this is not a satisfying answer because I myself don't know exactly what's going on there, but from a practical perspective this solved the problem for me multiple times, so it might help you as well.